# How to install/build any c++ library/package on VScode for Windows10?

Tags: c++, plot, build

I'm new to c++ and I have written a code. I need to plot using matplotlibcpp at [matplotlib-cpp](https://github.com/lava/matplotlib-cpp)

However I do not know how to install it. I've tried vcpkg, but it doesn't work.

I want to be able to use it in my code when I do:

> #include "matplotlibcpp.h"

For example in Python, I would simply do the following to install a third party package or library:

1. On admin cmd prompt: pip install [ package name ]
2. On Python editor: import [ package name ]

Is there anything similar for c++ in VScode on windows?

Comment: Have you tried following the [instructions](https://github.com/lava/matplotlib-cpp#installation)?

Comment: @Alan Birtles The instructions is about installing on Ubuntu but I am on Windows. I don't know how to install using Cmake

Comment: Are you able to successfully compile your code if the library isn't included? Does your code have hints like red squiggles when you make a mistake? This could be an issue with how your project is configured or how VS Code is configured, we need a bit more context to figure out the cause. Also matplotlib should work with vcpkg, but you may need to configure vcpkg to work with VS Code as well.

Comment: @AugustinPopa My code works fine in c++, but when I include << path/matplolib-cpp>> it says file cannot be found!